Building EURGBP basis
I would like to track the basis between Euro and some other currencies. Bloomberg currently only shows EURvsUSD basis and any other currency basis is also against USD. I was wondering, given the two sets of basis EURvsUSD quoted in EUR and GBPvsUSD quoted in GBP, how could the EURvsGBP basis be constructed from that data? Any book or paper reference would also be helpful.
Thanks!

Can you get away with simply assuming that for some third currency CCY, such as GBP, the EURCCY cross-currency basis is the difference between USDCCY and EURUSD?

This paper may help: https://hdl.handle.net/10419/206543

I thought about doing EURUSD basis minus GBPUSD basis, but I would need to swap the GBPUSD basis to EUR currency somehow, or I would be calculating the difference between two basis which are quoted under a different currency (EUR and GBP).

Exactly, you'd assume that the differences in the cost of funding commute.

Thanks! I will try with that. The final goal was to build the GBP Cashflow CSA curve, so let's see if I can get to a similar curve building these EURGBP basis. Thank you so much!

I'm not 100% happy because I suspect this may not hold for some less liquid currency pairs, but foe GBP it may be close enough.

Yes! You were right. For GBP the results are pretty good, but I have tried with AUD and there are some deviations starting at the 10Y tenor. Thanks for your help!

ICAB opens ICAP Global Menu -> ICAP EMEA -> XCCY Basis Swaps -> vs ESTR -> GBP
It has tickers like EBXOQQC ICPL Curncy. This might help to track the basis.

I did not know that, this will be super useful. Thanks!
